# How do you remove command-line error: invalid macro definition: __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__=16 in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, intellisense

When I create a new .h file in Visual Studio Code, I get red squiggles with the error message `command-line error: invalid macro definition: __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__=16`. I have not defined any custom macros. When I create a .cpp file this is not an issue, however if I change the file extension it becomes one. This error does not appear in a .cpp file, however it does apply if I create a .h file and change the file extension to .cpp. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into File->Preferences, and find option "_Cpp › Default: Intelli Sense Mode", and choose a compiler. In my case, I chose gcc-x64 and the problem went away.